# If/Then Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I cannot figure out why this formula isn't working:

```
=IF(A2="160850",TP,IF(A2="202006",BL,IF(A2="203646",MM,IF(A2="203917",KT,IF(A2="200265",MP,IF(A2="201447",JB,IF(A2="170566",VB"")))))))
```

Cell A2, A3, and so on, represent commossion codes that are specific to a sales rep. 
So, if Cell A2 equals 160850, then I need the cell I place this formula in (C2) to display TP, and so on, based on the formula above.

I have checked and this looks okay to me. However, when I enter this formula in, I get a message that states The formula you entered contains an error. 
Can anyone assist?

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: that seems to be a typo - VB"" ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to put your return values inside quotes, otherwise Excel assumes that `TP` is a valid name in the workbook (i.e., an address, named range, or variable).

```
=IF(A2="160850","TP",IF(A2="202006","BL",IF(A2="203646","MM",IF(A2="203917","KT",IF(A2="200265","MP",IF(A2="201447","JB",IF(A2="170566","VB")))))))
```

There may be additional errors, but this one is apparent.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be simpler to use a lookup table? List all your commission codes in one column, e.g. Y2:Y10 then list the linked sales rep (initials) in the next column (Z2:Z10) and you can then use this formula copied down the column

`=VLOOKUP(A2,Y$2:Z$10,2,0)`

Comment: +1 it's always simpler to use a lookup table :) Even put it on a hidden worksheet, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The last set of double quotes should be parentheses:

```
=IF(A2="160850",TP,IF(A2="202006",BL,IF(A2="203646",MM,IF(A2="203917",KT,IF(A2="200265",MP,IF(A2="201447",JB,IF(A2="170566",VB)))))))
```

You also probably want to take the agent numbers out of quotes or it'll return false because the number entered is numeric and you're looking for a string. The Codes should be in quotes, though e.g. IF(A2=160850,"TP",....